# Add variation to the Search Results based on a solr field

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrj, lucidworks

I have a solr field which has a set of values. Is it possible in solr to return results that are varied based on that field.
Eg: My field contains "ValueA","ValueB" and "ValueC". So if rows is set to 3 then instead of returning all results from "ValueA" it should give me one from each field value (Considering they have the same scores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the [Result Grouping / Field Collapsing](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)
or the [CollapsingQParserPlugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/jiBqAg).

The CollapsingQParserPlugin is newer (since Solr 4.6), faster and more appropriate for your problem, I guess, as it does not effect the structure of the results.

Just add this to your solrconfig.xml:

```
<queryParser name="collapse" class="org.apache.solr.search.CollapsingQParserPlugin"/>
```

You can then collapse your result by adding the following parameter to your query:

```
fq={!collapse field=my_field}
```

or in Solrj:

```
solrQuery.addFilterQuery("{!collapse field=my_field}");
```

Collapsing means: For each value in `my_field` it only retains the document with the highest score in the result set.